# Cómo obtener dato serial transmitido desde arduino por bluetooth, capturado por una app en processing android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Recurro a uds porque no entiendo el por que no puedo obtener el dato serial transmitido desde arduino mediante bluetooth y capturado por una app en processing android.

Ya sé que el dato enviado es una cadena de bytes, eso lo sé y que al ser recibidos hay que convertir esa cadena en Int por ejemplo, pero no hay caso, no logro ver con el comando text en la pantalla del celular.

Acá les paso el código (trabajo con la libreria ketai, probe con otro sketch sin esta libreria y funciona bien la recepcion de datos, pero me resulta impractica para agregarla a mi programa)  :

```
import android.os.Bundle;      // onCreate Bundle
import android.content.Intent; // onActivityResult Intent
import ketai.net.*;
import ketai.net.bluetooth.*;  // KetaiBluetooth
import ketai.ui.*;
 KetaiBluetooth bluetooth;
 KetaiList klist;
 int valor ;
 String info = "";
 boolean isConfiguring = true;
 String info = ""; 
 
void onCreate(Bundle instancia_almacenada)
{
  super.onCreate(instancia_almacenada);
  bluetooth=new KetaiBluetooth(this);
}

void onActivityResult(int codigo_solicitud, int codigo_resultado, Intent datos)
{
  bluetooth.onActivityResult(codigo_solicitud,codigo_resultado,datos);
}

void setup()
{
  fullScreen(JAVA2D) ;
  bluetooth.start();
  bluetooth.discoverDevices();
  bluetooth.getPairedDeviceNames();
  bluetooth.connectToDeviceByName("PROTOTIPO"); // Conecta por el nombre del dispositivo
}

void onBluetoothDataEvent(String who, byte[] data) {
     
 if (data != null){
                String str = new String(data);
          
                   info = str.substring(0, str.length());
                   int valor = Integer.valueOf(info);
                          
                background(0);
                fill(255);
                textSize(80);
                text(info, width / 2, height / 2);
                
                println(valor);
              
            }
```

El programa compila perfecto y se ejecuta bien en Android , como asi tambien se establece la conexión mediante bluetooth , solamente no puede obtener el dato serial , muchas gracias .